# How to change the Formik validation Programatically

Tags: reactjs, react-native, formik, yup, formik-material-ui

i am stuck on one point on the formik while creating the validations. I have one object inside that i have 5 values . which are boolean

```
subs = {
math = true,
science = true,
computer= true,
medical = true,
g.k = true 
}
```

i have an input filed for all subjects and i want to medical filed to be null only when the selected stream is commerce or arts. if the selected stream is medical then it must be positve integer value. how can i make a validation schema for to achieve this one in formik

Comment: Please share the additional code that you've tried first. You can use [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) to do that

Comment: Share some demo